# Sorting a list by the nth character of a string c#

Tags: c#

Is there a simple way to sort a list based on the 4th character of a string? I have a list of countries with codes in front of them; "us united states" is one string in my list and I want to ignore the codes ("us ") before the full country name.

Answer (score 3):

```
list.Sort((x, y) => x.Substring(3).CompareTo(y.Substring(3)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the other answers, this way of performing the sort ***will not*** create unnecessary substrings. Instead, it takes advantage of the existing [string.Compare(strA, indexA, strB, indexB, length)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7tax739(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that accepts string offsets for comparison.

```
list.Sort((s1, s2) => string.Compare(s1, 3, s2, 3, int.MaxValue));
```

There are other useful `string.Compare` overloads, that also accept offset values, that you can use to tweak the comparison behavior. (e.g.: ignoring case, etc.)

Comment: + 1 for using existing comparison operations without manipulating the string literals. All I would add is a length check to make sure `s1` and `s2` are both at least 4 characters long (to avoid a potential `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`)

Comment: @PhilGref And what should be done if a string is shorter than 3 characters? Should it be ignored, or lead to throwing a custom exception, or to setting a warning flag? Without knowing it, keeping default error handling could be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it - `List<string>` is your original list variable

```
[List<string>].OrderBy(s => s.Substring(3)).ToList();
```

This works

```
var l = new List<string>(){"us unites states","uk united kingdom","ca canada"};
foreach (var s in l.OrderBy(s => s.ToLower().Substring(3)).ToList())
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Note `ToLower`, so you don't compare upper case to lower case letters (if you have both)